# Ubuntu laravel production migration not working

Tags: laravel, ubuntu, migration, production

The migration works fine on my local server but on my production server which is a Ubuntu 18.04 it shows this error, it's really odd that it works fine on my localhost but not here, I have already looked around for possible solutions but nothing worked for me, I hope one of you can help me solve this problem!

I'll got here below the migration where it goes wrong, and the MySQL error and I found a command where you could check for the latest MySQL foreign key error!

```
Brands migration:

public function up()
{
    Schema::create('brands', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->id();
        $table->string('brand_name')->unqiue;
        $table->integer('categories_id')->unsigned();
        $table->foreign('categories_id')
        ->references('id')->on('categories')
        ->onDelete('cascade');
        $table->boolean('brand_hidden');
        $table->string('brand_color');
        $table->timestamps();
    });
}
php artisan migrate:fresh:

Dropped all tables successfully.
Migration table created successfully.
Migrating: 2014_10_12_000000_create_users_table
Migrated:  2014_10_12_000000_create_users_table (0 seconds)
Migrating: 2014_10_12_100000_create_password_resets_table
Migrated:  2014_10_12_100000_create_password_resets_table (0 seconds)
Migrating: 2019_08_19_000000_create_failed_jobs_table
Migrated:  2019_08_19_000000_create_failed_jobs_table (0 seconds)
Migrating: 2020_07_08_080611_create_categories_table
Migrated:  2020_07_08_080611_create_categories_table (0 seconds)
Migrating: 2020_07_08_124956_create_brands_table

   Illuminate\Database\QueryException

  SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1215 Cannot add foreign key constraint (SQL: alter table `brands` add constraint `brands_categories_id_foreign` foreign key (`categories_id`) references `categories` (`id`) on delete cascade)


Latest forein key error:

2020-12-05 12:48:15 0x7f0680762700 Error in foreign key constraint of table laravel/#sql-1f8_19:
 foreign key (`categories_id`) references `categories` (`id`) on delete cascade:
Cannot find an index in the referenced table where the
referenced columns appear as the first columns, or column types
in the table and the referenced table do not match for constraint.
Note that the internal storage type of ENUM and SET changed in
tables created with >= InnoDB-4.1.12, and such columns in old tables
cannot be referenced by such columns in new tables.
Please refer to http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/innodb-foreign-key-constraints.html for correct foreign key definition
```

Comment: The error says that `id` on `categories` does not have an index associated that matches the constraint you are giving it. Can you share that migration too?

Answer (score 3):

The error is most probably due to mismatch of the column datatypes.

`id()` creates a column with datatype of `unsignedBigInteger`

So if the `categories` table has primary key defined by `id()` then the foreign key column on brands table should be declared as `unsignedBigInteger`

The foreign key naming convention should be singular of the table being referenced - category_id for referencing categories table on id column

Try modifying your migration as below

```php
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('brands', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->id();
        $table->string('brand_name')->unqiue;
        $table->unsignedBigInteger('category_id');
        $table->boolean('brand_hidden');
        $table->string('brand_color');
        $table->timestamps();

        $table->foreign('category_id')
            ->references('id')
            ->on('categories')
            ->onDelete('cascade');
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the feedback it worked for me :) I only got one left which doens't wanna cooperate!

```
        Schema::create('products', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->id();
            $table->string('product_name');
            $table->unsignedBigInteger('brand_id');
            $table->unsignedBigInteger('product_image_id')->nullable();
            $table->boolean('product_hidden');
            $table->timestamps();

            $table->foreign('brand_id')->references('id')->on('brands')
                ->onDelete('cascade');
            $table->foreign('product_image_id')->references('id')->on('product_images')
                ->onDelete('cascade');
        });

   

Schema::create('product_images', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->id();
            $table->string('product_image_url');
            $table->unsignedBigInteger('product_id');
            $table->timestamps();
            
            $table->foreign('product_id')->references('id')->on('products')
            ->onDelete('cascade');
        });
```

It gives this error!

```
 SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1215 Cannot add foreign key constraint (SQL: alter table `products` add constraint `products_product_image_id_foreign` foreign key (`product_image_id`) references `product_images` (`id`) on delete cascade)
```